# Deploy Android Application with Initial SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database, android-rom

I need to use a Database in Android and I have read that a good way at the moment is using Room Library.
But my case is a little different I don't want the database to write information on runtime I want to deploy the application with an SQLite dabase already created and with data inside.

What is the folder to put the DB file in Android Studio project? How to access this from app using Room?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this
library `implementation'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'`

and paste the database in your asset folder and in your sql helper call put the database name

```
 private class SqL extends SQLiteAssetHelper{

    public SqL(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

where `DATABASE_NAME` is your databse name and `DATABASE_VERSION` is your database version

Comment: It seems to be a very good library to avoid manually copy. I see that it's unmaintained. Are you using it in actual developments?

Comment: @JuanDYB Yes so far no issues

Answer (score 0):

Put db file at your project assets folder

Comment: And how I have to access it in the code? Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: @JuanDYB Sorry for the late reply. please refer to my above answer.